# Фронт в значении "Место, район военных действий"

Tags: лексика, стилистика

В годы Великой Отечественной войны слово "фронт" употребляли в этом значении: **"место, район военных действий и расположение действующих войск во время войны.*** Уехать на ф. Письма с фронта. Был на фронте (воевал). Южный ф. Западный ф. Уже завтра город может стать фронтом.

Корректно ли это употреблять слово "фронт" в этом значении по отношению к современным войнам? Мне не довелось ещё встретить нигде употребление этого слова по отношению к современным войнам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понятие **фронта** по отношению к воюющей стране употребляется в значении *передовой* (букв. "передней") *линии*, воображаемой линии противостояния войск. Это простая аналогия с фронтом (передней частью) волны - морской или радиоволны (как в теоретической радиотехнике). В случае войны при этом подразумевается, что в неё вовлечены *вся территория и население* страны - всеобщая мобилизация, вся промышленность перестроена на военное производство и т. п. В таких условиях страна делится на **фронт** и **тыл**, что и наблюдалось во многих странах в двух мировых войнах. В современных условиях не так много стран, полностью занятых войной, именно поэтому фразеологии с упоминанием *военных фронтов* мы почти не слышим.

Однако мы слышим о *фронтах* борьбы с эпидемией, которая воспринимается как форма войны. На этих *фронтах* находятся врачи в больницах и эпидемиологи, в то время как все население на *остальной территории* вовлечено в воображаемую битву и защищается доступными средствами. Отсюда видно, что **фронт** - понятие *относительное*.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander. Мои сомнения оказались не напрасными.

Answer (score 0):

У большинства слов в языке не одно значение, особенно у глаголов. Во времена второй мировой у слова «фронт» существовало как минимум два значения: обобщенное название для места скопления войск и пространство перпендикулярное расположению войск. По понятным причинам, термин в первом значении не используется, не является общеупотребительным и, следовательно, общесогласованным, а поэтому не рекомендуется его использовать. В случае появления каких-то точек боевых действий, обычно формируется лексика для их обозначения, вроде «поехать на Донбас», «поехать в Сирию», и «поехать на фронт» было такого рода временной общеупотребительной лексикой. Слово во втором значении является элементом специальной терминологии военных.

Comment: Спасибо. Но вы,кажется,не совсем верно поняли мой вопрос.